# Match and copy data between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets, one main and other that is constantly changing. I want to compare data and if there is a match, copy data to the main worksheet.

I have created a userform inside the main worksheet where there is a textbox asking the file name ("Change" in this example).

After I have inserted the file name “Change“ and press ok, it should open that worksheet and another userform with 3 text boxes (`Ref;City;Data`) and an OK button.

So I can manually fill the userform with the correct columns in the textboxes by looking at the Excel file:
`Ref=E;City=G; Data=I.`

Pressing OK, should fill the “Main“ worksheet by matching information on two columns and copying the info in the columns that I have specified to the "Main" Worksheet, and close the "Change" worksheet.

**Edit**

I believe I have improved the code a bit.

To open the worksheet by the text box, followed by a new UserForm:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    myfile = "C:\Users\ss\Desktop\Reports\" & TextBox1.Value
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile
    Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

To match Values between workbooks and copy different columns specified:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Values As Range
    Dim V As Range
    Dim Ref As Range
    Dim City As Range
    Dim Data As Range
    Dim x1, y1, y2, y3, V1, V2, V3, V4

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Set Values = Range(Range("B4"), Range("B4").End(xlDown))

    For Each V In Values
        x = V.Value

        Workbooks("Change.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        V1 = TextBox1.Value
        V2 = TextBox2.Value
        V3 = TextBox3.Value
        V4 = TextBox4.Value

        With Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("C:I")
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Cfind = .Cells.Find(what:=x, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Cfind Is Nothing Then GoTo line1

            y1 = Cfind.Columns("V2").Value
            y2 = Cfind.Columns("V3").Value
            y3 = Cfind.Columns("V4").Value

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Activate
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        End With

        V.Offset(0, 1) = y1
        V.Offset(0, 2) = y2
        V.Offset(0, 3) = y3

line1:
    Next V

End Sub
```

I can't see anything wrong and when I run this, there is no error.

**Edit**
I've changed the code to define the ranges that I want and it seems that its working but the matching and copy isn't.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

    myfile = "C:\Users\sst1brg\Desktop\Relatorios\" & TextBox1.Value 
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile 
    Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical 

    Dim Values As Range 
    Dim Ref As Range 
    Dim City As Range 
    Dim Data As Range 
    Dim ValuesRng As Range 
    Dim RefRng As Range 
    Dim CityRng As Range 
    Dim DataRng As Range 
    Dim Cfind As Range 
    Dim OriValues As Range 
    Dim V As Range 
    Dim x As String 
    Dim x1, y1, y2, y3 

    Workbooks("Change.xlsx").Activate 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    Windows("Change.xlsx").Activate 

    Set Values = Application.InputBox( _ 
    prompt:="Select the Values cell", Type:=8) 
    Set ValuesRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Values, Values.End(xlDown)) 

    Set Ref = Application.InputBox( _ 
    prompt:="Select the Ref cell", Type:=8) 
    Set RefRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Ref, Ref.End(xlDown)) 

    Set City = Application.InputBox( _ 
    prompt:="Select the City cell", Type:=8) 
    Set CityRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(City, City.End(xlDown)) 

    Set Data = Application.InputBox( _ 
    prompt:="Select the Data cell", Type:=8) 
    Set DataRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Data, Data.End(xlDown)) 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Activate 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
        Set OriValues = Range(Range("B3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)) 
        For Each V In OriValues 
            x = V.Value 

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
            Workbooks("Change.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate 

            With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:I") 
                On Error Resume Next 

                Set Cfind = .Cells.Find(what:=x, Lookat:=xlWhole) 
                If Cfind Is Nothing Then Goto line1 
                y1 = Cfind.Range("RefRng").Value 
                y2 = Cfind.Range("CityRng").Value 
                y3 = Cfind.Range("DataRng").Value 
            End With 

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
            Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Activate 
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select 

            Range("C4").Value = y1 
            Range("D4").Value = y2 
            Range("E4").Value = y3 
line1: 
        Next V 
    End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you talking about a "file" (`"text box asking the File name"`) or a "sheet" (`"it should open that worksheet"`). It would be helpful to show the code you have attempted to write - this site is intended to help you "fix" not "create" code.

Comment: Hello floris, im talking about a Macro with a text box for me to manually fill (example:Change) and by pressing ok, it opens a workbook in my desktop that has that name (C:\Users\ss\Desktop\Change.xlsx), maintains the first workbook active, and starts a new UserForm. I can add the code that i have but know, are nothing but simple parts that don't work together.